# Java 8/11 JNI on Mac M1 "building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64"

Tags: java, cmake, java-native-interface

I am trying to do some exploration with Java JNI in Mac M1, while got caught by some exceptions,

using `cmake --build build` to build the project

```
[ 20%] Building Java objects for sbmcprj.jar
[ 40%] Generating CMakeFiles/sbmcprj.dir/java_class_filelist
[ 60%] Creating Java archive sbmcprj.jar
[ 60%] Built target sbmcprj
[ 80%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sbmc.dir/native/com_damonyuan_jni_HelloWorldJNI.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX shared module libsbmc.dylib
ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/libjawt.dylib, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
[100%] Built target sbmc
```

it gives the warning that `building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64`, and once run the JNI project,

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Djava.library.path=/Users/damonyuan/Desktop/sbmc-jni/native -classpath /Users/damonyuan/Desktop/sbmc-jni/target/classes com.damonyuan.jni.HelloWorldJNI
error: null
/Users/damonyuan/Desktop/sbmc-jni/native
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'void com.damonyuan.jni.HelloWorldJNI.sayHello()'
    at com.damonyuan.jni.HelloWorldJNI.sayHello(Native Method)
    at com.damonyuan.jni.HelloWorldJNI.main(HelloWorldJNI.java:15)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

the exception as above is thrown.

The whole testing code is [here](https://github.com/damonYuan/jni-test), could anyone help tell me how to make it run?

I have tried to google and different combination of params in cmake config, while in vain.

——

One thing I haven’t verify is that the jre installed is for x86 architecture or m1, will check and update later.

Secondly in Mac it’s clang that takes effect, g++ is just a alias as clang, it’s also suspicious.

Comment: The error explicitly states that you're trying to link with an x86_64 library, so yes, that is the problem.

Comment: yes, that the reason....